# Checking greater character

Tags: c++

Giving 5 inputs, program will check which entered character is the greater (assume characters are alphabets here only).

This is the code I've written (All variables are of char data type).

Problem is, it's **printing the last entered character every time** which makes it obvious the logic is faulty..

Here's the code I've written:

```
cout << "Enter a character ";
cin >> chr;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter a character ";
    cin >> chr2;
    if (chr > chr2)
    {
        store = chr;
    }    
    else
    {
        store = chr2;
    }
    chr = chr2;
}

cout << "Greater character is "<< store << endl;
```

Comment: What sort of debugging have you done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making your code *far* too complex! What you need to do is first set your 'rolling' maximum (the `store` variable) to a value lower than any possible input (let's say 0) then run a *single* loop to read in each of the test characters. On each input, compare the given character to your 'rolling' max and, if it's greater, set that rolling max to the given input.

Something like this:

```cpp
char store = 0, chr;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    cout << "Enter a character ";
    cin >> chr;
    if (chr > store) store = chr;
}
cout << "Greatest character is "<< store << endl;
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: This is perhaps the way I was thinking to implement it but couldn't. Thanks for the suggestion!!

Comment: You're welcome! Incidentally, if you want to avoid the "arbitrary initialization" of the 'rolling max' you can - as you did - read in the first value *but* read it into `store`, then run the loop 4 times.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are always comparing with the previous character, not the biggest-seen character.

In my opinion, the control flow can be simplified. Try something like this:

```
/* Rather than pull the first iteration out of the loop, begin with the minimum value */
char greatest = std::numeric_limits<char>::min();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  std::cout << "Enter a character: " << std::endl;

  char input;
  std::cin >> input;

  /* We only need to replace `greatest` with `input` if `input` is greater */
  if(input > greatest)
  {
    greatest = input;
  }
}

std::cout << "Greatest character is: " << greatest << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code `chr = chr2;` in the last before line tells the code to store the last entered value in the chr and this means you are comparing only the last and last before entered value in the program,

To change the program to suit your need , Change `chr = store;` which tells the program to store the greatest char entered to be stored inside `char` variable .

`````
    cin >> chr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a character ";
        cin >> chr2;
        if (chr > chr2)
        {
            store = chr;
        }

        else
        {
            store = chr2;
        }
        chr = store;
    }

    cout << "Greater character is "<< store << endl; ````


Hope this helps!!
`````